# Firebase group security rule configuration

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase, and I was trying to setup security rules where I want users to be grouped by dynamically created groups.  I also want the user to be able to read all content from the same group, but not other groups.

When I create new users and assign them some groups using push, I get data like the following:

```
{
"groups" : {
 "default" : {
  "-Jtcdyniz1yVwNQCGSAR" : {
    "user" : "simplelogin:5"
  },
  "-Jtd114KNQ-rqh6-rlnI" : {
    "user" : "simplelogin:7"
  }
}
},
"users" : {
"simplelogin:5" : {
  "group" : "default",
  "name" : "123"
},
"simplelogin:6" : {
  "group" : "default1",
  "name" : "1"
},
"simplelogin:7" : {
  "group" : "default",
  "name" : "23"
}
}
}
```

Can anyone help here? How can I setup authentication rules? I have tried with following but it doesn't seem to work...

```
    {
        "rules": {

            "users" : {
                "$userid" : {
                  ".read" : "data.child('users').child($userid).child('group').val() === data.child('users').child(auth.id).child('group').val()",
                  ".write" : "$userid === auth.uid"
                  }
              }
        }
    }
```

I assume that this should be fairly simple use-case but unfortunately didn't get much help.

Whatever posts that I found had direct users inside a group instead of a subchild of a random, unique string.

**EDITED:**

I tried with edited rules like :

```
    {
        "rules": {
            "groups" : {
                ".read" : "true",
                ".write" : "true"
              },
            "users" : {
                "$userid" : {
                  ".read" : "data.child('group').val() === root.child('users').child(auth.id).child('group').val()",
                  ".write" : "$userid === auth.uid"
                  }
              }   
        }
    }
```

but I did not get much help.

For code, I have added it as a fiddler at : http://jsfiddle.net/digish_gabhawala/ytwmokg0/

What I want at the moment is two simple things:
1> as a user, I should be able to edit my name
2> when I click button, I should be able to get names of all users in my group.

When I tried the code as in fiddler, I am getting permission issues.

It would be great if I can get what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: `data.child('users')` -> `root.child('users')`, and this entire clause seems unneeded: `"data.child('users').child($userid)`; since you're already in exactly that node, you can just do `data.child('group')`)

Comment: Aside from the remarks I made above, it is impossible to say if these are the correct rules without also knowing how you intend to use them, i.e. without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I just want to make sure that If I am logged in with any user from default group, I should be able to see all the names in the same group. This way, I intend to be able to share data across uses.

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question please. Because if you'll try something like `ref.child('users').orderByChild('group').equalTo('default').on('child_added'...` that won't work. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I updated the post as per your suggestions but still I am missing something as functionality is not working as per expectations. Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: "2> when I click button, I should be able to get names of all users in my group" This will never work with your current data structure, as it requires a query of the type I typed in my last comment (and the link to the relevant documentation). You can only query `ref.child('users')` if you have `.read` access to **all of** `/users`.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I got that point. Also I updated auth.id to **auth.uid** and it started working for point no 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the issue is that you're using `$userid` instead of `$uid`. So changing this should make it work. I'm using `$uid` in my security rules.

Comment: The `$` things are variables and can have any name. All that matters is that the variable name you use in property name matches what you have in the `.read`, `.write` or `.validate`.